# Filtering files by partial name match

Tags: powershell

I have a network share with 20.000 XML files in the format

```
username-computername.xml
```

There are duplicate entries in the form of (when a user received a new comptuer)

user1-computer1.xml
user1-computer2.xml

or

BLRPPR-SKB52084.xml
BLRSIA-SKB50871.xml
S028DS-SKB51334.xml
s028ds-SKB52424.xml
S02FL6-SKB51644.xml
S02FL6-SKB52197.xml
S02VUD-SKB52083.xml

Since im going to manipulate the XMLs later I can't just dismiss properties of the array as at the very least I need the full path. The aim is, if a duplicate is found, the one with the newer timestamp is being used.

Here is a snipet of the code where I need that logic

```
$xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem "network share"
```

Here I'm just doing a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($xmlfile in $xmlfiles) {
  [xml]$xmlcontent = Get-Content -Path $xmlfile.FullName -Encoding UTF8
  Select-Xml -Xml $xmlcontent -Xpath "  "
  # create [pscustomobject] etc...
}
```

Essentially what I need is

```
if ($xmlfiles.Name.Split("-")[0]) - duplicate) {
  # select the one with higher $xmlfiles.LastWriteTime and store either
  # the full object or the $xmlfiles.FullName
}
```

Ideally that should be part of the `foreach` loop to not to have to loop through twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) to group files by a custom attribute:

```
$xmlfiles | Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] }
```

The above statement will produce a result like this:

```
Count Name    Group
----- ----    -----
    1 BLRPPR  {BLRPPR-SKB52084.xml}
    1 BLRSIA  {BLRSIA-SKB50871.xml}
    2 S028DS  {S028DS-SKB51334.xml, s028ds-SKB52424.xml}
    2 S02FL6  {S02FL6-SKB51644.xml, S02FL6-SKB52197.xml}
    1 S02VUD  {S02VUD-SKB52083.xml}
```

where the `Group` property contains the original `FileInfo` objects.

Expand the groups in a `ForEach-Object` loop, sort each group by `LastWriteTime`, and select the most recent file from it:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Desc | Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: deadly. thanks a mill Ansgar. exactly what i was looking for. everything else i tried i ended up loosing the original object properties. while i should have just gone with a group + sort combo as per your example.
already implemented in my code and works perfect just as intented. thanks again!

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, the proposed sort | select approach, even though its an extra loop, does not come with a huge time penalty

VERBOSE: total xmlfiles 17086

VERBOSE: get-content run in 3.1642018
VERBOSE: filtered xmlfiles after removal of duplicates 13908
VERBOSE: filtering took 23.7152372 seconds