# Using Group-Object : How to Keep x number of each directory and delete all others

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to use Group-Object to group differents directories in order to  delete them but keeping the 2 most recent.

Reference:[Filtering files by partial name match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617391/filtering-files-by-partial-name-match)

This path will always be creating folders with different names, you never know what will be the name. So I can not use `$_.Name -like "Folder_*"`.8

Example: In the following tree I just want to keep `Folder_4`, `Folder_3`, `Test_4`, `Test_3`.

```
 Directory: C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_1
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_2
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_3
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_4
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_1
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_2
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_3
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_4
```

I have not figured out how to use Group-Object in the following script, I´m still getting errors:

```
    $path = "C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST"
Foreach-Object {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}
}
$keep = 9
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] }
         Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: You cannot just take code from a different question and expect it to work for you without any modification. In your case you need to remove the numbers from the end of the folder names to make suitable grouping properties.

Comment: Solved:

gci "C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST" -Recurse | 
where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |
Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[0] } |
foreach {
  $_.Group |
  sort CreationTime -Descending |
  Select -Skip 7 |
   foreach { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force }
  }